# Number of configurations of the universe

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I have read that quantum mechanics says that the amount of possible particle configurations is $10^{10^{122}}$ to be exact in the universe. Do we know this figure to be exactly true to the exact figure? Wouldn't we need to know a true theory of quantum gravity to know the exact answer? Is the amount exactly that figure or just an estimate?

Comment: John, you have the power to delete question with no upvoted answers, but you *should not* remove the content from posts and leave it on the site. Posts here are not ephemeral, they are expected to *last* delete it if you must but do not erase it that way.

Comment: I'm sorry I was embarrassed by my question in the end will not happen again

Answer (score 3):

This is clearly an estimate, not an exact figure. It comes from ideas about quantum gravity (not proven but very strong conjecture) that say that [the maximum entropy of a region](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bekenstein_bound) is

$$ S = \frac{A}{4 \ell_P^2}, $$

where $A$ is the area of a surface bounding the region and $\ell_P \approx 10^{-35}\ \mathrm{m}$ is the [Planck length](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_length).

Now [entropy is a measure of the number of configurations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann%27s_entropy_formula) available to a system (units where $k_B=1$):

$$ S = \ln \Omega. $$

Putting this together with the observed size of the universe for $A$ gives roughly the figure you mention.